# Material Stepper Control - Reducing the space between Headers

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using the Material Stepper on mobile, I would like to use it in horizontal mode but I can't seem to identify the CSS to reduce the distance between the headers. I would like to just have the numbers in mobile mode and have more steps visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

to remove extra margin you may add this in your .css file

```
  /deep/ .mat-horizontal-stepper-header{
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out one of my steps had a control which was stopping the Stepper from correctly resizing. All Sorted Now.